# Reading text from a php page and inserting it in a db

Tags: php, mysql, database

How to read a text from a Php page and insert it in a table using mysql
for e.g my page contains

"Hello World" and I need to insert this piece of text in a table "hello".

Comment: I am  trying the first p tag and the last p tag from my html page, then string off the p tags from the extracted text since it will include both <p> and </p>. Also  I wanted to know wheter Datamining are applied overhere. I do not know much about data or text mining but I assume it can be of help  to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have active flag "[allow_url_fopen](http://www.php.net/manual/es/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen)" (if you want open external URL), could you use [file_get_contents](http://es.php.net/file_get_contents):

```
<?php
// Connect to mysql...
//

$page = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/');
mysql_query("INSERT INTO hello (page) VALUES ('$page');
?>
```

Comment: Hey guys I figured out what I needed to read a text or any kind of data from your page have to use: 

$a = the value u want to read it can be from a db, a external doc and so on


    $start = strpos($a, '<p>');
    $end = strpos($a.$timedb, '</p>', $start);
    $paragraph = substr($a, $start, $end-$start+4);
    $paragraph = html_entity_decode(strip_tags($paragraph));  
    echo $paragraph;

works perfectly fine, then comes the INSERT INTO tablename VALUES ($paragraph).

Comment: I recommend to use [preg_match_all](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php)